Buffering only one side of polygons in a layer having multi polygons of same dimension

I have rectangular polygon features of equal dimension in my layer. The current buffer option buffers whole polygon (where height as well as width are changed). I want to buffer only one side or just one out of height/width. Is there a simple way of doing it? Also as I mentioned, there are many polygons (700+ in a file), a method where I can edit them all together is preferred.
Note: I am aware of the one-sided buffer and single-sided buffer options in QGIS, but I guess they are good for line but not for Polygon feature.

I think you will need to break you polygons into lines and pick jiust the side you are interested in buffering

Polygons only have two sides -- the inside and the outside. If you want left/right sides, you need to cast to polyline first.

You need a unique id column in your polygon layer, if you dont have one create it using Field Calculator. Name it id
Then:

Convert the polygons to line with Polygons to lines. This will create one line for each polygon.
Split the line into the four sides with Explode lines
Extract either the two long sides, or the two short sides with the SQL expression:

SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "id" ORDER BY st_length(geometry) DESC) AS rnum
FROM input1) sub
WHERE rnum<3

For the long sides use DESC order, else use ASC. The expression number the four sides from 1-4 for each "id"/polygon ordered by the line length, and selects number 1 and 2.

Single sided buffer:



Thanks @Bera It was helpful answer to buffer either of the sides. Creating Polygons back again using the buffered side was bit tricky as the buffered side was not intersecting well with the other side, but managed that as well.

What should I do when someone answers my question?

You can use Geometry Generator or Geometry by Expression (see here for details) to translate the polygon and use pythagoras/sinus function to calculate the delta-x- and delta-y-distances, based on the polygon's main angle.
Use the following expression and change the value in line 3 from -90 to 0, 90 and 180 to shift the polygon in the four main directions of the polygon (right, up, left, bottom). The value of 9000 is the distance, you can adapt this as you like:
with_variable(
    'dir',
    -90,
translate(
    $geometry, 
    9000 * degrees (sin (radians( @dir-main_angle( $geometry)))), 
    9000 * (degrees (sin (radians( @dir-90-main_angle( $geometry)))))
))

Red: initial polygons; blue: shifted ones:


Edit:
Use the following expression to be able to create the buffers only (without the initial polygon) on any of the four sides. On line 3, you can keep only those of the values that you need: if you delete e.g. the value 0, no buffer will be created on the top, as can be seen on the next screenshot. Here, 5 is the buffer distance:
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach(
        array(-90,90,180),
        difference (
            translate(
                $geometry, 
                5 * degrees (sin (radians( @element-main_angle( $geometry)))), 
                5 * (degrees (sin (radians( @element-90-main_angle( $geometry)))))
            ),
            $geometry
        )
    )
)

Showing the solution with creating blue buffers to initial yellow polygons on the rights side (-90), left side (90) and bottom (180). If you add 0 in line 3, a buffer on the top will be included:


Based on the idea by @Bera to use the four sides of the rectangle, I propose another variant. Convert the segments of the polygon's boundary to lines and collect them in an array. Like this, you can use index operator []  to use only one of the four sides to buffer.
Use this expression with Geometry by expression. Change 0 at the end of line 2 to 1, 2 or 3 to create buffers around the other sides of the rectangle.
buffer (
    geometries_to_array (segments_to_lines($geometry))[0], 
    400  -- change buffer size here
)


